# How to implement a counter (variable that is updated every time the contract is called) in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, inheritance

Parent and child contract are:

```
contract test{
   uint a ;
   function test() {
       a = 1;
   }
   function val() returns(uint){
       return a;
   }  
}

contract test2 is test{ 
    uint b = a++;
    function show() returns(uint){
        return b; 
    }
}
```

Every time I call `show()` I would like to get the new value of `b` as `a` is incremented afterwards. I'm not able to implement this using the above code. Is there an alternative for static variable in Solidity? If not, what should be done to get the desired working?

Comment: What is the desired behaviour? So you want `a` to store internally a count for the number of times that `show` was called. Also you want to have return that count and increment it, right?

Answer (score 3):

This returns `b` then increments `a` (and fixes the initialization of `b`):

```
contract test2 is test{ 
    uint b;
    
    function test2() {
        b = a++;
    }
    
    function show() public returns(uint){
        b = a++;
        return b; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the desired behaviour is that your contract stores an internal counter and anytime that the function `show` is called you retrieve the value of that counter and increment it by one afterwards, then this would be such a contract

```
contract test2 is test{
    function show() public returns(uint256 b) {
        b = a;
        a += 1;
    } 
}
```

The variable `a` is an internal counter variable and lives inside the contracts storage. Even though you inherit `test`, there is only one storage for the contract. You may add some visibility and mutability to variables. For instance `uint256 internal a` would not be visible from the outside, `uint256 private a` would not be visible by `test2` (but it still exists in this single storage of the contract) and `uint256 public a` would be visible from the outside. The variable `b` does not live in the contract's storage. It is a temporary dummy variable in this implementation.